# Getting Task List Comments Field value as blank while retrieval through SP 2013 PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, task-list

I am referring below blog to copy one Task List item to another archival List in SP 2013 Portal. While copying the list items from source list the Comments field value for each item in source is retrieved as blank.
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/10/copy-list-items-between-sharepoint-lists-using-powershell.html

Can you please guide me why this is happening so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to get Approval Status column using this script?

Comment: Yes, I am able to get the "Status" field value.

Comment: @KailashSahoo Did you run into any error message when executing the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested with the script and it works as expected, for **Comments** field as well.

Make sure you have the **same type** of columns (Multiple lines of text, for example) added to the two lists.

You can add the default Site Column Comments via *List settings* > *Columns* > *Add from existing site columns* > **Comments** to avoid mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!. I cross checked based on your suggestion and all settings are fine. The script is also working fine for me , but only for few records the comments field value is coming as blank.

Comment: @KailashSahoo Might be something wrong with the fields themselves. Try update them manually and watch for special characters, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Comment: Hi, When the comments field gets fetched , then it comes along with html elements. is there anything I need to follow to get the actual commented text instead of along with Html elements.